# Demand for iPhone App ported to Android?

Tags: iphone, android, statistics, mobile-website

Although not really a programming question I believe many developers would have come across this and therefore give the best answer.

Currently I am developing an App for iPhone for the organisation I work for. Its close to release and there is heaps of interest when I present it but the occasional question comes up am I going to port it to Android. My answer is I would like to but according to web stats more than 90% of phones hitting our website are iPhones and the other 10% is declining (probably people migrating away from Blackberry, last count was 98% was iOS)

Now if you read the media many people would like you to believe that its a split market between Android and iPhone but this might be just in the U.S where the single carrier for the iPhone has limited its consumer uptake because all the information available to us (at least in my organisation) states otherwise.

I was curious to hear from other people who have looked into these stats both inside and outside the U.S because when I tell the person asking that there is no demand they dismiss it and say its growing, once again contradicting the stats available for our organisation.

I am really interested in Android dev so don't really want to hear that I should just make it to give people an alternative, it's hard to justify to management that I should spend their money to deliver content to 5% of our market. Currently it makes more sense to make a cut down web App rather than an Android App.

Be interested to hear your thoughts. Cheers

Comment: Betting on iOS alone means betting that all the other phone manufacturers are going to be content to let Apple own the market in the long run (or that it would do the unthinkable and license the software to others).  Given the sheer number of manufacturers now offering an Android device most are predicting that it will become comparable if not dominant in market share over the next year or two.  Also, you aren't likely to see an iOS phone as the basic with-plan freebie, but a cutdown android device in that role is entirely imaginable in the near future.

Comment: @Chris - That isn't really helpful. I'm not betting on iOS, the demand isn't there and if there is a demand later on doesn't mean we cant develop the App for Android. The plans on offer with Android compared to iOS doesn't affect me in any way as I'm not buying them, our customers are buying iOS

Comment: If you aren't developing for android and blackberry, then you are by definition betting on iOS, which is to say betting that Apple will continue to dominate the market over all other vendors.  Obviously that is not an outcome those other vendors will allow.  So it's only a matter of how long - a year, two years?  Do you want to be prepared for when it happens, or do you want to play catch up after the fact?

Comment: So what you are saying is we should develop the app for android, blackberry and palm even though we have less than 5% total for all of those devices? Why not make a web based semi functional App and then when the demand is there develop on device app for anything that has over say 15% use?

Comment: The web app could be a very good answer - it's more that you need to be prepared for the inevitability of iOS loosing its present degree of dominance, as there's no way that one hardware manufacturer can continue to shut out ALL others in the degree that Apple's first-comer position temporarily enabled.  BTW, you do know that android user agent strings are Mobile Safari, though mention android as the OS, right?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, but one about business issues like market share.  Also, I don't know that there can be a definitive answer to this question, because it's phrased to promote discussion.

Comment: @Chris You obviously have drunk the Android juice as your comment is exactly the same as every android fanboi. I purposely phrased the question to avoid this discussion. Currently our customers are on iOS and there is a move away from other devices, not towards. There are many other alternatives to iOS but currently, at least in my country where we aren't bound to one carrier, Android has yet to get any notable market share and with continuing fragmentation among devices / app stores and bloatware on the devices Win Phone 7 looks very possible to take over android and who knows, maybe iOS.

Comment: @Brad Yeah I know but as I said in my question programmers would have come across this problem before and Ginamin's answer best answers it and I have marked it as such

Comment: On the contrary, I think there's a lot seriously wrong with android.  But the question is not one of carriers but of phone manufacturers - other manufacturer's won't be content to play 2nd fiddle to Apple, and given its momentum and backing along with tolerable technical qualities Android is by far the most pragmatic of current solution for them to leverage to quickly catch up - ie. it's likely to be the VHS of smartphones.  But by all means keep track of and if warranted support the others as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, I would argue it simply depends on your market. For instance, in my location Android users are increasing steadily. It still took us a long time to commit resources for development. Plain and simple, until recently, there wasn't enough return value to develop an Android app. If your Android market is only a small percentage of your market, then the resources would probably better be spent within your main competencies (i.e. for my company, developing more iPhone apps). It is easier to make a presence for a new app or upgrade in a market you are already established in. After creating the Android app, you would need to spend more resources on creating brand awareness, which if you already have a successful iPhone app, wouldn't be necessary if you simply created more iPhone apps. Also, let's be honest, the Android marketplace is a bit of a mess and hard to market on. Don't get me wrong, I have a healthy respect for Android and its capabilities, but unless you can see a return on the app, there is no point in developing it.

Comment: I agree the Android app market is a bit of a mess and with new App stores being released it looks like its going to get worse before it gets better. This is what I'm sort of scared of, spending time and money when win phone 7, bada, palm, blackberry might win out in the end. Our customers are on iPhone almost exclusively atm and I think making a web or cross compilable code base until there is a clear winner might be money better spent

Comment: Just wondering since you actually talked about the Android market share you dealt with, Does the country you live in have iPhone on the sole carrier? Also what approx % of your customers use Android to iPhone?

Comment: I live in Taiwan and we have 3 carriers for the iPhone, which makes it quite popular here. However, one carrier offers the best service(Chung Hua telecom) and they hold most of the iPhone contracts, last I heard. Apple also has a pretty strong market here as Taiwanese like to be trendy. Our Android market here has increased beyond the global average to over 7% (all relayed to me, so I don't have a source for you to check out). We have just started our Android development  and I am a bit curious to see how it turns out, but it will be a number of months before we can actually see the results...

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the type of application you are developing, it might be worthwhile to utilize a mobile framework that allows you to easily develop for both devices (plus many others). This is not the solution for all applications, such as those where speed is critical or games, but for many apps it might help. Have you looked at [Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/) or [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/)? Just be careful to do plenty of research and make sure they support all of your requirements before jumping in.

It's difficult to answer your main question because the statistics related to mobile devices varies immensely, especially related to the type of application you are developing. Certain types of users prefer one type of phone and those users typically will use only certain features. For example, BlackBerry users are less likely to download games than iOS users.

Comment: I have a feeling they might limit me too much, we run a custom auth here which was a pain to get around on the iPhone, Its only web based but it is not mobile friendly.

Answer (score 2):

For web apps

The approach suggested above is a nice approach because phonegap, appaccelerator or rhomobile do provide a sort of a virtual environment for applications developed in HTML, ruby. However, that might not be sufficient in a number of cases.

One of the approach i have seen developers adopt a lot for native apps

If you have developed your application using C code for the application state machine and lower levels then that code can be ported straight away to Android and be plugged into Android app using JNI technology.

The UI will have to be re-created.

Answer (score 1):

What is the value to your organization of that 5% of customers being able to have a native Android app, versus the company's development time/resource cost?

Now that you've done all the app architecture and design work (including artwork, documentation, etc.) for the iPhone app, will a porting or rewrite for Java/JNI/Android take less development time by some multiple?

Comment: Although half will be easy as its database structures, network resources and so on, I feel there will be a lot of work redoing the whole UI, probably 1/2 the time spent on the iPhone App has been spend on UI development (not design) and I would think most of that would have to be done again

Answer (score 1):

I think the most important factor is that if your company have the resources to maintain two version of the app. Would it be more beneficial to maintain native iOS app and a mobile version of the site? Since as you mentioned the usage of non-iOS devices of you website, as a metric lead a conclusion of such already.

As a matter of fact, if you have put most of the logic to the server back-end, writing an android app would not take anywhere longer than writing an iOS app, as long as you've programming experience in Java.

Also contrary to common beliefs, since the market share of Android phones are not as good in your place (would you mind telling us where your company is resided in?, it would in natural have less localized app in your geographical location. So creating an app specifically for them would gain more acceptance. That is fact, is a good thing. (see: [Long Tail theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_Tail))

Comment: Australia - Not really, there was a lot of effort in management and proposals to get the iPhone App off the ground, the reason it did was the vast majority of our customers are on iPhone. Although it will be easier for Android as the services already exist, no one in the organisation has experience with Android dev (lots of Java dev though) and we wouldn't hire someone specifically to do it especially with 5% market share

Comment: Also, first adopters are a resoundingly poor market. They are overly critical and fickle. I wish I had hung on to my Modern Marketing tactics book now... I always thought the class was useless until I started on iPhones.

Comment: From my experience that doesn't take long to learn Android dev - shorter comparing to iOS SDK + Obj-C IMHO. Since there are plenty of Java programmers it would not take you any longer. What is really important is that your market share is highly tilted towards iPhones, so it would be wise to support iPhones first and get the app mature and straight before developing another platform.

Comment: I agree with that sentiment completely. And you are correct that it is easy for a java programmer to hop over to Android. I don't think the iOS SDK is complicated for someone who's previously learned Obj-C/Cocoa. But yes, the problem is there are many more Java programmers than Obj-C programmers out there, so you make a valid point.